# SMTP mail failing in Grails app (MS Exchange and no authentication)

Tags: java, debugging, grails, smtp, jakarta-mail

We have a Grails 1.2.1 app that uses code from the mail plugin. We had to adapt the code since we need to connect to a variety of SMTP hosts, not just one like the plugin at that time permitted.

Anyway, its been working fine for years, until we needed to connect to an Exchange server configured without smtp authentication.

Usually this config setting works fine with Exchange:

```
mail.smtp.auth=true;mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=2525;mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=true;mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

For this case, I'm using:

```
mail.smtp.auth=false;mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=2525;mail.smtp.debug=true;mail.debug.auth=true
```

With this particular smtp server, we get this:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:415)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:341)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:337)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
```

**1st off, how do I get debug messages to show up,** I cannot seem to turn on any detailed logging.

I've got debug level tracing enabled in the config.groovy for these patterns:

```
                ,"org.springframework.mail"
                ,"javax.mail"
```

**2nd, any options I can try to get past the auth issue?** I've seen one answer using javaMail's connect() without the uid/password, but our app calls

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSender.send(org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage)
```

Comment: Setting "mail.debug=true" ought to get you debugging output.  If you're using JavaMail 1.4.7, you should be able to get debug output using the com.sun.mail.smtp Logger; see the [javadocs for the com.sun.mail.smtp package](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) (scroll to the bottom).

Comment: Using springframework, so I assume the logger class would be  `org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl` But in spite of logging at debug level for "org.springframework.mail.*" I see nothing in the logs

Comment: org.springframework.mail might control the logging done by the Spring-specific classes, but it shouldn't have any effect on the JavaMail classes.  Did you try com.sun.mail.smtp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got past the auth issue with mail.smtp.auth=false and setting both the userid and password to null.

No success on obtaining the debug level trace output